# How does Multiple shards per module support works in ODL nitrogen

Tags: opendaylight

The module-shards.conf file mentions the following :

> For Helium we support only one shard per module. Beyond Helium we will support more than 1

Have ODL Nitrogen and trying to use "module-shards.conf" like the following :

```
module-shards = [
    {
        name = "default"
        shards = [
            {
                name="default1"
                replicas = [
                    "member-1"
                ]
            },
            {
                name="default2"
                replicas = [
                    "member-1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

That seems to be working as karaf shows the 2 shards successfully created 
for the same module "default". But how the data is distributed among 
the 2 shards is not clear, can application control/decide which data goes in which of the module shards.

I am not clear how the application config tree data and the operational tree 
data for a given module be stored under different shards for the same module.
If there are multiple shards for the same module, can application decide/control
which shard to use for storing a particular type of data. For example, 
can application decide to store the config tree in "default1" shard 
and operational tree in "default2" shard for the same module "default" ?

Is it possible to disable operational tree component for one of the shards of 
a given module, say disable operational tree component for shard "default2" 
of module "default" with 2 shards namely "default1" and "default2" ?

Answer (score 0):

While it says for Helium only one shard per module is supported, that is still the case - support for more than 1 was never implemented. There hasn't been a use case for that. The shards are created but transactions are only routed to one of them (ie picks the first one that is found).