# Can module-shards.conf be configured differently on different cluster nodes?

Tags: opendaylight

I remember the question asked on this forum about multiple shards per module [how-does-multiple-shards-per-module-support-works-in-odl-nitrogen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895621/how-does-multiple-shards-per-module-support-works-in-odl-nitrogen)
The answer was that MD-SAL really uses only the first shard to start transactions for the module. 
Can it be used for splitting a module among different cluster nodes? If on the first node module default is configured to have two shards default-1 and default-2, but on the second node it is configured to have only default-2 shard, it looks like we may have two leaders for the same namespace (on node 1 it will be default-1 and on node 2 it will be default-2). It will be very desirable but is it possible?
Is it possible to configure a module differently on different nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to configure it in that manner but not sure why it would be desirable. Also only 1 shard per module is supported so no point in defining default-1 and default-2 on node 1. If the purpose is for each node to maintain its own local copy of the data in the default space, then that can be achieved by configuring only the local node as a replica.

Comment: Such configuration will be desirable because it allows to use one node to populate data and another node to read it while both nodes are shard leaders for the same namespace. So performance will not degrade.

Comment: I'm not clear on that. If you define 2 shards, default-1 and default-2, regardless of where the replicas are, they are separate entities. But if such a configuration works for your use case then go for it :)

Comment: Will these two shards have a common data tree in memory or they will have separate data trees?

Comment: Separate - each shard runs raft separately and is isolated from other shards.